# Drag down formula without changing the value of row 1?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have a formula to calculate the total score of a review:

```
SUM(B1*B3,C1*C3,D1*D3,E1*E3)
```

[Excel Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAT2n.png)

is there a way to to drag the formula down from the total column without changing the value of B1, C1, D1, and E1?

Right now when I drag I get this:

- Instance 2

  `=SUM(B2*B4,C2*C4,D2*D4,E2*E4)`
- Instance 3

  `=SUM(B3*B5,C3*C5,D3*D5,E3*E5)`

What it should do instead when drag is this:

- Instance 2

  `=SUM(B1*B4,C1*C4,D1*D4,E1*E4)`
- Instance 3

  `=SUM(B1*B5,C1*C5,D1*D5,E1*E5)`

I'll be glad for any help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your formula to anchor the row numbers, like this:

```
=SUM(B$1*B$4,C$1*C$4,D$1*D$4,E$1*E$4)
```

If you want to drag the formula left or right, you'll also need to anchor the column letters by preceding them with `$` as well.

Comment: You’re close, but this is currently incorrect. Only the _1 values should be anchored, not the others. And the formula should use the third row, not the fourth.